# How can Django keep an API user logged in without a browser or return token?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-ninja

https://github.com/mugartec/django-ninja-auth/blob/bf36b4583a37213001131678d5ecda07f92ba2f6/ninja_auth/api.py#L33

It doesn't return any token, so how to does it identify them post-login for subsequent requests?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it does `django_login` - means it authenticates user using session/cookies for  subsequent requests